# nuxt3 server routes rewrite

Tags: javascript, nuxt3, nitro

I have a server route that reasons that I won't go into needs to `http://my-domain.com/~/images/filename.jpg`

I have created the folder structure with a folder name ~ and all works as I would expect however I cannot add this code to my repo as it won't pick up a file called ~, is it possible using nuxt or nitro to take that URL but using a different folder structure to run it, so the requests comes in at ~/images, but uses /server/routes/images/[file].js to do the actual processing?